# Update with sub query running slow

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying write a query to run an update on a table with around 1 million records, the query is expected to update around 10000 records.  The query takes around 10 minutes to complete which is too slow for my requirement. 
below is the query

```
update   ABC   t1 
 set amount_pct = (select (t1.amount / b.masteramt) * 100  
 from (select id, mstr_group, year, month, sum(amount) as masteramt  
 from ABC where id = 110 
 group by id, mstr_group ,year, month)  b  
 where b.id = t1.id and b.mstr_group  = t1.mstr_group  
 and b.year *100 + b.month = t1.year * 100 + t1.month AND b.masteramt != 0) 
 where t1.id = 110
```

I tried creating a materialized view and used that instead of the original table in the select query 
Query for materialized code

```
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv1 AS 
 select id, mstr_group, year, month, sum(amount) as masteramt  
 from ABC 
 group by id, mstr_group , year, month
```

and re wrote the above query as

```
update   ABC   t1 set amount_pct =
 (select (t1.amount / b.masteramt) * 100  from 
 (select * from mv1)  b  
 where b.id = t1.id and b.mstr_group  = t1.mstr_group  
 and b.year *100 + b.month = t1.year * 100 + t1.month AND b.masteramt != 0) 
 where t1.id = 110
```

the query was faster than the original query but still took around 7 minutes to complete . Is there a way to modify this query to run any quicker ?
I am using oracle 11g and the table ABC has indexes on id and mstr_grp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the `group by` in the subquery.  Something like this should work:

```
update ABC t1 
    set amount_pct = (select t1.amount / sum(b.masteramt) * 100  
                      from ABC b
                      where b.id = 110 and
                            b.id = t1.id and 
                            b.mstr_group  = t1.mstr_group and
                            b.year * 100 + b.month = t1.year * 100 + t1.month 
                     ) 
where t1.id = 110;
```

Then, you want an index on `(id, mstr_group, year, month)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . The `group by` was not required but even after removing the `group by` there was no improvement in the execution time of the query

Comment: Adding the index worked . I am a newcomer to sql could you please tell why the original indexes on `id` and `mstr_group` had no effect on the performance while this composite index reduced the time to 1/10th of the original time it took  to run.

Comment: @Random . . . In general, one index is going to be chosen for a given set of conditions between two tables.  If the columns are split between two different indexes, then Oracle has to chose one of them (or neither) -- and that is suboptimal.